# Ubuntu Budgie is now an official flavour (starts properly with 17.04)!

Tags: discussion, scope

[Ubuntu Budgie Remix](https://budgie-remix.org/2016/11/08/its-official/) is now an official flavour! [Though 17.04/ZestyZapus](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/ubuntu-budgie-now-official-ubuntu-flavor) (to be released in April, 2017) will be the first officially supported flavour, so questions on that should not be closed as off-topic. Though versions prior to that are still considered off-topic, and so is it until it is released (as it is currently still in development).

Comment: so there is not an official release yet ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind: Nope, that is yet to come. :)

Comment: While Budgie Remix may be an official flavor, that will not take effect until Zesty is released; therefore until that time it's considered under the same rules as the "In Development" release (17.04 currently), in that it's offtopic.

Comment: @ThomasWard: Ok, I have added that! Thanks! :)

Comment: Are we seeing lots of Budgie questions?

Comment: @Anwar not that I've seen - it's only recently become a 'flavor' so probably not.

Comment: If someone sneaks out with the code, could this be described as a 'budgie smuggler'?

Comment: Wow, this remix looks really nice. I might consider using something other than Unity as my default desktop since a very long time!

Comment: Is the [tag:budgie] tag enough, or should we create [tag:ubuntu-budgie]?

Comment: Don't you mean "Prior to release" rather than "versions prior to that"? After all, prior to official release it will still be a development version with the same strictures as any other dev version I would think.